# What's the meaning of "crowded field"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

> "You need word of mouth for this type of film and that's what this
>   weekend was all about," said Sony distrivution head Rory Bruer, who
>   granted it's a "crowded field."

What's the meaning of **"crowded field"**?

Does it just mean that the field(the movie market) is flooded with many new films?

Comment: yes, that's what he's referring to.

Comment: Could you give some more context? What was the title of the movie and what was it about?  There is a possibility that Bruer was also making a joke.

Comment: If you are talking about the same movie as in the previous question, please edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the meaning of "crowded field"?
>
> Does it just mean that the field(the movie market) is flooded with
>   many new films?

Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Additionally, if the movie had some connection with agriculture for example it would be a joke as well. We'd need context to know if a pun was intended.

> field - A particular branch of study or sphere of activity or interest.
>   [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/field)

Comment: Why only agriculture? "Field" is a general word...eg, he worked in the field of molecular biology.

Comment: I mean that it would be a **pun** if the movie was about agriculture. If the movie is about molecular biology then there is no pun -- it is just the general meaning of the word.  I've changed the wording of my answer to make that clearer.